# Multidimensional Array in Realm Swift (Maximum depth exceeded error)

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I want to make a 3D Array with Realm and I use List to accomplish this.
This is the code for my RealmDatabase:

```
class Sensors : Object {


    dynamic var type = ""
    dynamic var name = ""

    let buttonAr = List<buttons>()

}

class buttons: Object{
   let  buttonsAdded = List<objectNameTopic>()
}

class objectNameTopic: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var topic = ""
}
```

And this is what I use to call it:

```
var saving = Sensors()
var saving2 = objectNameTopic()
var but = buttons()
var array = ["on", "off"]
var array2 = ["1","2"]
var allSensors = useOfRealm.objects(Sensors.self)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    addSensor()

    for i in 0...array.count-1 {
        addSensor2(name: array[i], topic: array2[i])

    }

    if allSensors.count > 0 {
        print(allSensors)
    }

}


func addSensor() {

    try! useOfRealm.write {

        saving.type = "topic1"
        saving.name = "mike"
        useOfRealm.add(saving)


    }

}

func addSensor2(name: String, topic: String) {

    try! useOfRealm.write {

        saving2.name =  name
        saving2.topic = topic
        useOfRealm.add(saving2)

        but.buttonsAdded.append(saving2)
        saving.buttonAr.append(but)

    }

}
```

This is what I get when I print the results:

```
Results<Sensors> (
    [0] Sensors {
        type = topic1;
        name = mike;
        buttonAr = RLMArray <0x6100000fd900> (
            [0] buttons {
                buttonsAdded = RLMArray <0x6100000fdb00> (
                    [0] <Maximum depth exceeded>,
                    [1] <Maximum depth exceeded>
                );
            },
            [1] buttons {
                buttonsAdded = RLMArray <0x6180000fd180> (
                    [0] <Maximum depth exceeded>,
                    [1] <Maximum depth exceeded>
                );
            }
        );
    }
)
```

Any Ideas of what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're only instantiating one `saving` and one `saving2` instance, and reusing them multiple times. It may not be the cause of the problem, but Realm is an object database, so you should be instantiating a new object each time. Same probably applies to `but`, although it's not clear why this exists rather than just being a list property on `Sensors`.

Comment: You're right about that I found it out a few hours before when I was trying to fill my db with a for and it returned only the last item because it was overwriting everything else. I will try to aply these changes to this code too and see what happens

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `<Maximum depth exceeded>` in the XCode console output is what you fear, fear no more. It's just a way the console is telling you that the object hierarchy is too deep for showing it to you, but the object(s) are there accessible through code.

Just try to print the content of your result by iterating through it and printing each child object instead of printing only the root.

Comment: Yes you're right! Thank you! I used this line to check it: print(allSensors[2].buttonAr[0].buttonsAdded[0])

Comment: I was afraid my data was missing :D